# Change wp_get_attachment_image attributes (src and srcset) on specific custom field

Tags: custom-field, images

I'm using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) to output images in an image carousel called [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/). [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) supports image srcset with lazy loading.

Here's my basic ACF markup which uses [wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image):

```
<?php
  $image = get_field('image');
  $size = 'gallery';
  echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
?>
```

This nicely outputs on the front end, like so:

```
<img
  width="1164"
  height="450"
  src="image-1164x450.jpg"
  srcset="
          image.jpg 1164w,
          image-300x116.jpg 300w,
          image-768x297.jpg 768w,
          image-1024x396.jpg 1024w,
          image-2328x900.jpg 2328w,
          image-1680x649.jpg 1680w,
          image.jpg 3492w
        "
  sizes="(max-width: 1164px) 100vw, 1164px"
>
```

[Flickity Docs](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#lazyload) specify that you should use `data-flickity-lazyload-srcset` and `data-flickity-lazyload-src`. This means changing the output on [wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image).

I've achieved this via functions.php, like so ([source](https://jhtechservices.com/changing-your-image-markup-in-wordpress/)):

```
function gs_change_attachment_image_markup($attributes){

    if (isset($attributes['src'])) {
        $attributes['data-flickity-lazyload-src'] = $attributes['src'];
        $attributes['src']      = '';
    }

    if (isset($attributes['srcset'])) {
        $attributes['data-flickity-lazyload-srcset'] = $attributes['srcset'];
        $attributes['srcset'] = '';
    }

    return $attributes;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'gs_change_attachment_image_markup' );
```

This has worked perfectly on the frontend, like so:

```
<img
  width="1164"
  height="450"
  srcset=""
  data-flickity-lazyload-src="image-1164x450.jpg"
  data-flickity-lazyload-srcset="
          image.jpg 1164w,
          image-300x116.jpg 300w,
          image-768x297.jpg 768w,
          image-1024x396.jpg 1024w,
          image-2328x900.jpg 2328w,
          image-1680x649.jpg 1680w,
          image.jpg 3492w
        "
  sizes="(max-width: 1164px) 100vw, 1164px"
>
```

Unfortunately, this breaks the images on other custom or native fields using [wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image).

Is it possible to assign `gs_change_attachment_image_markup` function to a specific custom field so it's not being applied site wide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't be really able to tell which context the image is being used in in the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter, but you can pass custom attributes to `wp_get_attachment_image()` in the template directly with the 4th argument. Then you can use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` and `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` to get the values for those attributes:

```
$image = get_field('image');
$size = 'gallery';

echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, false, array(
    'src' => '',
    'srcset' => '',
    'data-flickity-lazyload-src' => wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image, $size ),
    'data-flickity-lazyload-srcset' => wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $image, $size ),
) );
```

Comment: Thank you, but this breaks WooCommerce: `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-product-functions.php on line 446. Any ideas?`

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. This code wouldn’t effect anything in WooCommerce. This would be caused by your original filter removing the src attribute.

Comment: I've removed the original filter. I think it has something to do with the empty `src` and `srcset` values. Adding `'src' =>'/'` and
    `'srcset' => '/'` removes the error.

Comment: Yeah your right sorry. The affected WooCommerce function was a filter applies to all images. It expects them to all have a src attribute.

Comment: The little hack I've used should do the trick :) Thanks for your help, you don't know how long I've spent on this!

Comment: Be aware that 'srcset' in $attr must be set (!empty), otherwise srcset will be generated anyways...

This is due to the WP function:

`if ( empty( $attr['srcset'] ) ) { // srcset being generated here }`

Setting it as 'space' or similar works fine for my purpose as the contents are being swapped anyways...